# Can't middleware send JSON to page components?

Tags: next.js

In the Next.js 13 version, I want to send a JSON object in the response from the middleware and use it in the corresponding server component.

If I send it using `NextResponse.json()` like the code, the JSON file itself will be rendered in the browser.

Is there any way to use that information in the server component?

middleware.ts:

[image]

localhost:3000:

[image]

Comment: Hi Gndy! Have you checked the below answer? Let us know please :)

Comment: very successful! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped! Feel free to accept it by clicking on the check button next to it to guide others :)

Answer (score 1):

When you return `NextResponse.json({user})` inside the middleware, you are stopping the request with a response, hence Next.js will not go to your page component.

Instead, you could use  `NextResponse.next()` and request `headers`:

```js
// middleware.js

import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request) {
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
  requestHeaders.set("x-user", JSON.stringify({ id: 1, use: "joneDoe" }));

  return NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: requestHeaders,
    },
  });
}
```

```js
// app/page.js

import { headers } from "next/headers";

export default function Page() {
  const headersList = headers();
  const user = JSON.parse(headersList.get("x-user"));
  // Check your server terminal:
  console.log(user);
  // Printing the string version on the screen for testing puspose:
  return <>{headersList.get("x-user")}</>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am storing such data in cookies. So the user can't modify it.

All of this is in JavaScript. You need to make little changes for TypeScript.

After `const` put this code:

```
    const response = NextResponse.next()

    response.cookies.set("username", user.userName, {
         sameSite: "strict",
         maxAge: 60 * 60 * 10, // 10 hours
         path: "/",
    });
    
    response.cookies.set("email", user.userEmail, {
         sameSite: "strict",
         maxAge: 60 * 60 * 10, // 10 hours
         path: "/",
    });

    return response
```

and remove your version of `return`

Then in the page where you want to use the user data you made, copy this:

```
function getCookie(name)
{
    const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++)
    {
        const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
        if (cookie.startsWith(`${name}=`))
        {
            return cookie.substring(name.length + 1);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and then you can get the cookie value like that:

```
const username = getCookie('username');
const email = getCookie('email');
```